# Create list of ordereddict from the list of objects

Tags: python

I have a code where i created the list of `dict` from `list of objects` using list comprehension.

**Sample code:**

```
version_info = [{"mnemonic": v.mnemonic, "unit": v.unit,
                 "value": v.value, "description": v.descr}
                for v in las.version]
```

How to change this to OrderedDict, because i want to maintain the order of the elements.

I'm using Python 2.7

Comment: ... use an `OrderedDict`? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: You meant to say OrderedDict constructor? will it accept more than one elements?

Comment: Have you looked at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)? Anyway, an `OrdereDict` constructor works exactly like a `dict` constructor, it accepts an iterable of key-value pairs. Not trying to be annoying, but usually this works better if you tell us what exactly is the difficulty you are encountering. Generally, one assumes you would have read the relevant documentation...

Comment: Although, to be fair, the docs seem to assume you will understand that `items` implies an iterable of key-value pairs...

Comment: Also, if you can switch to Python 3, Python >= 3.7 guarantees insertion order in plain `dict` objects, so your code would work as written...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I cant change to 3.7 version, when you say iterable of Key-value pairs.. what do you mean... because my list of objects only contains the values of keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of solutions:

```
version_info = [OrderedDict([("mnemonic": , v.mnemonic), ("unit", v.unit),
                 ("value", v.value), ("description", v.descr)])
                for v in las.version]
```

```
keys = ["mnemonic", "unit", "value", "description"]
attrs = keys[:-1] + ["descr"]
version_info = [OrderedDict([key, getattr(v, attr) for key, attr in zip(keys, attrs)])
                for v in las.version]
```

Both versions use the basic constructor of `OrderedDict`, which accepts an iterable of pairs. The first version is direct and hard coded, the second one uses a list comprehension to select the values based on a list of attribute names.